# SESSION array has nothing in it when it should

Tags: php, html, forms, session, post

I am having bad time getting SESSION to work in PHP.

I have a form the following action:

```
<form action="confirm.php" method="post">
```

And that has a button as such:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit">Proceed</button>
```

I have got `session_start();` on all my pages. After the form button, I have this code:

```
 <?php
    if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
    {     
       $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
       $_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['address'];
       $_SESSION['strtnum'] = $_POST['strtnum'];
       $_SESSION['height'] = $_POST['height'];
    }   
  ?>
```

On confirm.php I've got this:

```
<?php 
  print_r($_SESSION); 
  print_r($_POST); 
?>
```

The POST array has correct values but the SESSION array is completely empty with no variables or values at all.

I would like help understanding how fix this.

Thank you.

EDIT: I'm quite sure that the code doesn't actually reach the inside of the if statement. I added an echo in there to print an alert (yes I used ) and it doesnt work. So I'm not 100% sure that it enters the `if(!empty($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: *"I have got session_start(); on all my pages **(oh?)**. After the form button, I have this code: `<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
    {     
       $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];`"* - So, show it in your code where it's actually placed then. `On confirm.php I've got this:

<?php 
  print_r($_SESSION);` - <= no `session_start();` there.

Comment: I did not show the entire code in my confirm.php. I just showed the part that prints the arrays. I have session_start(); at the top of confirm.php

Comment: try to var_dump() your $_SESSION just before closing of if condition to ensure that everything is set in session variable there.

Comment: You've got `if(!empty($_POST['submit']))` but no form element with a name called `submit`, you need to have `name="submit"`.

Comment: @DaveChen I just tried that and it did not work. Thought it might have been the answer but I guess not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="confirm.php" method="post">
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Your form is being submitted to `confirm.php`,  thats where you should handle the `$_POST` and fill the `$_SESSION` values. Instead you are trying to do it in the same page that prints the form, but thats doing no good there because its not where the form data is being submitted to.

Comment: Thank you sir! This has fixed it. I understand now! Thank you very much sir